# DeferredResult from JMS Request/Reply with ListenableFuture

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I was looking for opportunities to improve the Rest Api we have exposed to external clients. During that exercise, I found I am barely taking advantage of the decision our integration team took to have backend integrations with JMS request/reply instead of traditional blocking SOAP request/reply.

Currently all the interactions to message broker are done using jmsOutboundGateway, because of which requesting thread has to wait for completion.  In order to scale RestAPI, I want to send JMS reply using DeferredResult from Spring MVC controller. The controller interaction with message broker is depicted below:

```
                Controller --> GatewayProxy --> JMSOutboundGateway
```

I am looking for opportunities to use ListenableFuture as return type of GatewayProxy, but I am unable to find a proper mean of achieving it using spring integration.

Below is the integration flow I am calling from controller:

```
<int:gateway 
        service-interface="ae.emaratech.ngx.service.PermitSearchService" 
        default-request-channel="permit_search_input_channel" 
        default-reply-timeout="${broker.jms.gateway.min.consumers}"/>


    <int:channel id="permit_search_input_channel" />

    <int:chain input-channel="permit_search_input_channel">


    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="person_number" expression="payload"/>
    </int:header-enricher>


    <int:transformer expression="#formatString(@api_messages['FIND_PERM_BY_PERSNO_MSG'],headers)"/>

    <int:header-filter header-names="JMS_*,jms_*,priority" pattern-match="true" />


    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="jms_type" type="java.lang.String" value="1" overwrite="true"/>
    </int:header-enricher>


    <jms:outbound-gateway 
        request-destination="permitsInboundQueue"
        reply-destination="permitsOutboundQueue" 
        receive-timeout="${broker.jms.gateway.timeout}"
        correlation-key="Correlation_ID" 
        connection-factory="brokerConnectionFactory">

        <jms:reply-listener concurrent-consumers="${broker.jms.gateway.min.consumers}"  max-concurrent-consumers="${broker.jms.gateway.max.consumers}"/>

    </jms:outbound-gateway>


    <int-xml:xpath-filter throw-exception-on-rejection="true">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="not(boolean(/*/ErrorDetails))"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-filter>             

    <int-xml:xslt-transformer
        xsl-resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/permit-to-json.xsl"
        result-type="StringResult" >
        </int-xml:xslt-transformer>

    <int:transformer expression="payload.toString()"/>


</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what problem you have, but the feature looks like:

```
ListenableFuture<String> result = this.asyncGateway.async("foo");
result.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        ...
    }
});
```

It is available since version [4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#_listenablefuture).

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I have made the question more elaborative now. Can you please please suggest what change is required to get JMS reply as ListenableFuture in above intergration flow?

Comment: ??? How does that relate to the `GatewayProxy`? You don't need to do anything. The `GatewayProxy` will do everything for you. Just make method on gateway interface with the `ListenableFuture` and configure gateway with the `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor`. Please, read that Gateway chapter more carefully.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have already tried that and by default gateway utilizes SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor for making the life easier but internally it creates more threads to perform the task asynchronously. What I was aspecting to have is that I should be able to return listenable future from "jms:outbound-gateway" after configuring int:gateway with empty  async-executor="". Upon receiving the response the gateway should directly be able to complete the Future in another thread.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing but `jms:outbound-gateway` isn't able to return `ListenableFuture`. It is blocking by nature and doesn't send reply until receiving it from the underlaying `ListenerContainer`. You can play with `inbound` and `outbound` channel adapters pair though...